# Default Constructor Compilation error expected unqualified id

Tags: c++, constructor, compilation, compiler-errors, try-catch

I want to build a Default Constructure which initialises my attribut (wich is an instance), from a File using a method loadfile. I also want an exception thrown if the file could not be loaded and if that is the case, I need to call my reset() function.

For the following code I always get the same error, at the try line, when trying to compile.

> Env.cpp:16:8: error: expected unqualified-id before 'try'

```
Env::Env() **// default constructor of Env class**
: terrain **// terrain is an instance of a class I declared in hpp file**
{
try
    {Env::loadFile();} **// the method loadfile throws an error it failed**
catch(std::runtime_error)
    {std::cerr << " Error " << endl;
        Env::reset();} **// calls reset function if file loading failed**
}
```

Comment: `try` and `catch` are keywords, not names and certainly not members of namespace `std`. Drop `std::` in front of them.

Comment: I removed the namespace tag std:: since try and catch are keywords, but I still get the same error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler thinks The `{ try ... }` is a *brace-init-list* for `terrain`. If you meant to default-construct it, do it like this:

```
: terrain{}
{
    ...
```

or this:

```
: terrain()
{
    ...
```

or omit the whole *member initialization list* if `terrain` is an instance of a `class`.